# Passing variables by @JavascriptInterface in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

As you probably know from the title I work with `Android WebView`. Though, I've got a specific question about `@JavascriptInterface`. I'm really curious if I can make the exact method which will be working on `Javascript` variables but will be called from `Android`. Let's say I have an object in Javascript which got a variable named `name`, then if I want to change this variable somehow I will use some kind of this function:

```
function () { 
    return this.name + ' my addition';
}
```

I would assign this function to another variable which will be used somewhere else. Now, I would like to do the same but in Android. Let's say I've got an object `Object obj` then this object has got it's `name`. My function made in `@JavascriptInterface` would be like this:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void changeName(Object obj){
    return obj.name + " my addition";
}
```

If I add the `JavascriptInterface` to my `WebView` named **"jsinterface"** I would do this like this in `Javascript`:

```
function() { 
    jsinterface.changeName(this.name); 
}
```

But to be honest it doesn't work because`obj.name` is null then. I know that's because I do not pass the `Object`. Is there any trick to make this what I want or I really need to use `webView.loadUlr("javascript: function() { ... }"};` ? I would like to avoid using `webView` here, that's why I ask this question.

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScriptInterface can only return or pass Primitive Data Types.

So it should be like this...

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void changeName(String obj){
   ........
}
```

Then, you need to turn a JavaScript Object to JSONObject. And turn the JSONObject to String.
Then you can pass it to "changeName."

And turn the String to JSONObject in Java code.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void changeName(String obj){
   JSONObject js = new JSONObject(obj);
   ....
}
```